# Field added to SpatiaLite table doesn't show in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have a spatial table in a SpatiaLite database that I'm editing in QGIS with no problem (the spatial table was created through SpatiaLite GUI).

I then added a text field to the table through SQL statement and I can edit this column in SQLite Studio or SpatiaLite GUI! However, this column doesn't show in QGIS, even if I add the layer to a clean project!

Any thoughts on how to update the field list in order to be correctly recognized in QGIS?

Comment: could you post the table structure details and the SQL you used to add the column?

Comment: It was the basic SQL structure to add a column: ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN column_name [field_type];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve this executing the Update Layer Statistics over the table through SpatiaLite GUI, which corresponds to the SQL statement:

```
SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics();
```

Apparently, this function updates the field info in the *geometry_columns_field_infos* metadata table.

After this, the field list shown in QGIS was correct.